# Can one format a table name property in a Dataset?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data source that has sever tables formatted with a date stamp.

**Example:**

- `dbo.TableName20180203`
- `dbo.TableName20180204`
- `dbo.TableName20180205`

When defining a dataset for Blob I can format the folder path based on the slice.

**Example:** `"folderPath": "mypath/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}"`

I would like to define the table name property like so: `"tableName": "dbo.TableName{Year}{Month}{Day}"`

In the blob dataset I define the `partitionedBy` property, but this does not appear to be allowed if the dataset type is a SQL table.

Another path I have considered but not tried is a stored procedure that accepts parameters and some dynamic SQL.

Is there a way to format the table name like I illustrated above?

Comment: I created a stored procedure and a stored procedure activity. I think this will work, but I am interested to know if there is a way to accomplish this as originally described.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using the copy activity and using a stored procedure as the source.

The stored procedure takes three parameters: `@Year`, `@Month` and `@Day`. I then use those parameters to build a select statement and run `sp_executesql`.

In the end I am able to output the data in slices with a frequency of `Day`.